# JSON path Parse error using Robot framework

Tags: arrays, json, robotframework

I'm trying to get the hobbyList from a different Json Array:

```
{

"hobby": {
    "hobbyList": [
        {

            "hobbyType": "Art",

            "hobbyTypeList": [
                {

                    "hobbyText": "Gunpla"                    
                    
                }
            ]
        },
        {

            "hobbyType": "Art",
            "hobbyTypeList": [
                {

                    "hobbyText": "Wood Craft"                    
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

with this query

```
${freeform}=        Get Value From Json     ${object}       $.hobby.hobbyList[.hobbyTypeList[.hobbyText
```

and I Expect to get the evaluation result

```
    ["Gunpla","Wood Craft"]
```

Using the above mentioned Json query it throws a parse error

```
Parse error at 1:33 near token . (.)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a JSON Query syntax error, you should using the query with `$.hobby.hobbyList[*].hobbyTypeList[*].hobbyText` and of course a more simple filter `$..hobbyText` will also working here.

You'd better test the behavior for the JSON query filter before using it in the robot case. It's easy to find some online tester via Google.

Comment: Hi Ji! Thanks man, Bless you. This is already tested with jsonpath evaluator.